Number of $n$-tuples of positive integers summing to $k$
I know that:
$$\left|\left\{(a_1,a_2,...,a_n) \in \mathbb Z_{\ge0}^n : \sum_ia_i = k\right\}\right| = \binom{n + k - 1}k$$
In other words, the number of ordered $n$-tuples of non-negative integers summing to $k$ is given by the binomial coefficient on the RHS.
I tried to figure out a way to find the formula in the case of tuples of $\mathbb Z_{>0}^n$, that is, positive integers instead of non-negative integers, but I couldn't figure out such formula. The case $n=2$ is trivial, since it's enough to subtract $2$ from the result (namely, the pairs $(n,0)$ and $(0,n)$), but in the general case it gets very hard and I believe the formula doesn't look nice (although I'd love to get proven wrong on this point).
So, can you help me finding such formula? Thanks in advance.

Hint: If $(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ are positive, then $(a_1-1,a_2-1,\dots,a_n-1)$ are non-negative.

How can it be $\binom{n-1}{k-n}$ if $k-n>n-1$ in some cases?

Sorry, I thought I deleted the first one. Deleted whole comment. It is $\binom{k-1}{k-n}=\binom{k-1}{n-1}.$ If $n>k, $ there are no such tuples.

Makes sense, thanks!

See also this answer.  In that answer, ignore all of the Inclusion-Exclusion discussion, review the Stars and Bars links, and then specifically see Addendum-2, at the end of the linked answer.
